# Getting the latest status of user before every calendar Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as below:

Table 1:

```
UserID  DateEntered Status
1   29/03/2021  a
1   30/03/2021  b
1   31/03/2021  a
2   01/04/2021  a
3   02/04/2021  c
2   03/04/2021  c
3   04/04/2021  a
4   05/04/2021  b
4   06/04/2021  a
```

Table 2 : A simple calendar table

Required output: For every date I want to return the latest status on or before it for every userID.

```
UserID  DateEntered Status  Calendar_date
1   29/03/2021  a   25/03/2021
1   29/03/2021  a   26/03/2021
1   29/03/2021  a   27/03/2021
1   29/03/2021  a   28/03/2021
1   29/03/2021  a   29/03/2021
1   30/03/2021  b   30/03/2021
1   31/03/2021  a   31/03/2021
1   31/03/2021  a   01/04/2021
1   31/03/2021  a   02/04/2021
1   31/03/2021  a   03/04/2021
```

Similarly for other calendar dates and other userIds.

Anyone has a clue how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why are the user ids all `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For every date I want to return the latest status on or before it for every userID.

In standard SQL, you can generate the rows using `cross join` and then use a join.  The key idea is to use `lead()` for the `join`:

```
select u.userId, c.calendar_date, t1.status, t1.dateEntered
from (select distinct userId from table1) u cross join
     table2 c left join
     (select t1.*,
             lead(DateEntered) over (partition by userId order by DateEntered) as next_DateEntered
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on u.userId = t1.userId and
        c.calendar_date >= t1.DateEntered and
        (c.calendar_date < next_DateEntered or next_DateEntered is null);
```

In SQL Server, you can also express this using `outer apply`:

```
select u.userId, c.calendar_date, t1.status, t1.dateEntered
from (select distinct userId from table1) u cross join
     table2 c outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.userId = u.userId and
            t1.DateEntered <= c.calender_Date
      order by t1.DateEntered desc
     ) t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd2b19ff1939b5b8b4df8068dc35e899) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi,  I tried with both the queries and it's not giving the correct result. For example the output is IDof calendar_date ArrearsStatus dateEntered
10003009 15/01/21 0:00 NULL 13/01/21 15:23
10003009 14/01/21 0:00 NULL 13/01/21 15:23
10003009 13/01/21 0:00 Stage 1B - Send Statement 15/12/20 11:35. However the status are as below Status User Id Date Entered
Stage 1A - Text 10003009 13/01/21 15:23
Stage 1A - Text 10003009 13/01/21 15:23
NULL 10003009 13/01/21 15:22
Stage 1B - Send Statement 10003009 15/12/20 11:35

Comment: @User05 No one can read your mind or see your "result". It is up to you to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that others can use to help you. But I caution **against** this approach. A query that generates your stated goal for every date will quickly become very inefficient as the number of rows in "table 1" grows along with the actual period of time you are interested in. And you have not defined that period either - which is an obvious oversight.

Comment: @User05 . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The results looks correct based on your description of the problem and the data you provided.  Any `NULL` values are because there is no status on or before that date.

Comment: @SMor : Apologies, I did not know hot to add a table of output in a comment. Upon checking again, I realised the solution is working perfectly. Also, I am giving time period in the where clause(Last 4 years) so that should be fine.